I'm trying to calculate the number of green cells in a row when clicked in an excel spreadsheet, but it only calculates them when the module is enterd
I programmed a spreadsheet to turn green when a cell is clicked, and I added a module to detect the total number of green cells in a row, but it only updates the amount of green cells in a row when the module is entered, how do I make it automatically calculate the amount of green cells when clicked.
I'm not sure this is the best place to look for advice for excel programming, but the excel subreddit was no help, so I don't know where else to look
I tried to make it so the module CountGreenCells() when a cell turns green would automatically update the number of green cells, but it only calculates it when the module is entered in to a cell
Spreadsheet
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("C4:Y322")
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        
        If Target.Cells.count = 1 Then
            
            Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            
        End If
        
        Application.Calculate
        
    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    
    Application.Calculate
    
End Sub

Module
Function CountGreenCells(rng As Range) As Long
    
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Dim count As Long
    
    count = 0
    
    For Each cell In rng
        
        If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then
            
            count = count + 1
            
        End If
        
    Next cell
    
    CountGreenCells = count
    
End Function


You need to add Application.Volatile True to the function.

Putting Application.Calculate inside Worksheet_Calculate may end up triggering an infinite loop...

In which column are your formulas located?

In the procedure SelectionChange replace the line:
Application.Calculate
with
Application.CalculateFull
Calculate alone does not recalculate UDF functions.
Another option is to add Application.Volatile to the function and then  you just need to use Calculate in Worksheet_SelectionChange.
I think the procedure Worksheet_Calculate is superfluous in this form.

A Worksheet SelectionChange: Highlight Cell and Count Highlighted Cells In Same Row

This code uses the A column to return the counts. Adjust!
IMO, there is no need for a UDF.
First, try out the code as is. Then start switching TOGGLE_COLOR and CHECK_ROW to see the differences in the behavior.
If none works as required, please share the reason behind it.


Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet1
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const COUNT_COLUMN As String = "A"
    Const TARGET_RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "C4:Y322"
    Const HIGHLIGHT_COLOR As Long = vbGreen
    ' Or:
    'Dim HIGHLIGHT_COLOR As Long: HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Const TOGGLE_COLOR As Boolean = True
    Const CHECK_ROW As Boolean = False
    
    ' Reference.
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = Me.Range(TARGET_RANGE_ADDRESS)
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(trg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If irg.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim WasHighlighted As Boolean
    
    ' Highlight.
    If Target.Interior.Color = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR Then
        If TOGGLE_COLOR Then Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        WasHighlighted = True
    Else
        Target.Interior.Color = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR
    End If
    
    ' Write count.
    With Target.EntireRow.Columns(COUNT_COLUMN)
        If CHECK_ROW Then
            If TOGGLE_COLOR Or Not WasHighlighted Then
                .Value = GetHighlightedCellsCount( _
                    Intersect(.EntireRow, trg), HIGHLIGHT_COLOR)
            End If
        Else
            If TOGGLE_COLOR Then
                .Value = .Value + 1 + 2 * WasHighlighted
            Else
                If Not WasHighlighted Then .Value = .Value + 1
            End If
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub

Standard Module, e.g. Module1

In this solution, the following is not used as a UDF but as a helper function in case, CHECK_ROW is set to True in the code above.

Function GetHighlightedCellsCount( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    ByVal HighlightColor As Long) _
As Long
    Dim cell As Range, Count As Long
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        If cell.Interior.Color = HighlightColor Then
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    GetHighlightedCellsCount = Count
End Function

